# Why is this code not working?It is supposed to continuously plug the output of the expression into its input

Tags: javascript

I tried plugging in the expression 1+1/x ,it should have printed the golden ratio 1.618 but it prints out 2.

```js
var num_iterations = 1
var x = 1
const max_iterations = prompt("Max Iterations: ")
var expression = eval(prompt("Expression to be repeatedly calculated: "))
console.log("loading...")
while (num_iterations <= max_iterations) {
  num_iterations++
  x = eval(expression)
}
console.log("The Answer is " + x)
```

Comment: At 10 iterations this does it https://jsfiddle.net/0gz6r732/ . 

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're calling `eval()` when you prompt for the expression. So `expression` doesn't contain the expression, it contains the result of evaluating it the first time. Then the loop keeps evaluating that result, not the expression.

Remove that extra call to `eval()`.

```js
var num_iterations = 1
var x = 1
const max_iterations = parseInt(prompt("Max Iterations: "))
var expression = prompt("Expression to be repeatedly calculated: ")
console.log("loading...")
while (num_iterations <= max_iterations) {
  num_iterations++
  x = eval(expression)
}
console.log("The Answer is " + x)
```